# jquery text(), interpret<br> as new line

Tags: jquery

Getting an element of the DOM like this

```
$('#id').content().text();
```

Problem arises with

If it gets this:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p><br></p>
<p>World</p>
```

Naturally in Html looks like:

```
Hello 

World
```

But this jquery `.text()` method returns: HelloWorld

How to interpret `<br>` as new line? <-> How to get the text exactly as I see it in HTML?

`.html()` gives all the HTML tags, which I don't want. I just need the plain text with spaces, if possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.text()` is plain text without formatting.  It is literally the concatenation of the text nodes without any other HTML codes (including new lines which are represented by `<br>` or `<p>` tags, not by newlines).

`.html()` is the exact HTML of a container tag.

If you use this, it will get you an approximation of your text with new lines:

```
var item = document.getElementById("id");
var text = item.innerText || item.textContent;
```

It's looking at both `.textContent` and `.innerText` due to browser compatibility issues.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Xs5P3/ for a working demo.

A Google search for "HTML to text conversion" gives a lot of options to investigate.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do that? (eliminate all but newline HTML tags)

Comment: @jacktrades - I added an option to my answer that seems to work.

Comment: Just note that innerText or textContent will NOT interpret <BR> tags as newlines. That fiddle shows newlines because there are actual newlines inside that div. Remove the newlines in the fiddles HTML source and the results will not be what you expect.

Comment: @eferrari - That is correct.  `.textContent` which is the modern implementation simply collects the text from all the text nodes in the `div`.  It ignores `<br>` since it does not contain text nodes itself.  I've updated the jsFiddle to show what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind a destructive (“modifying the HTML code”) operation:

```js
$("#id").find("br").replaceWith("\n").end().text()
```